# JSON find value and return object with key

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a program that searches through JSON objects to match values, when it matches a value I want it to return the object name along with the key associated with the matched value.

This is the code I currently have, it is matching the value and returning the object name as required, I need it to return the associated key with the matched value (I'm using the GSON library).

`testHarnessSensor` is the value to be matched, e.g. `chair`

```
ArrayList<String> currentActivity = new ArrayList<String>();
    int i=0;
    try {
      InputStream input = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/drink.json");
      JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
      jsonReader.beginObject();
      while (jsonReader.hasNext()) {
        String nameRoot = jsonReader.nextName();
        if (nameRoot.equals("Activities")) {                   
          jsonReader.beginObject();                            
          while (jsonReader.hasNext()) {
            String activityName = jsonReader.nextName();      
            jsonReader.beginObject();                         
            while (jsonReader.hasNext()) {                    
              String n = jsonReader.nextName();
              n = jsonReader.nextString();                 
              if (testHarnessSensor.equals(n)) {
                currentActivity.add(activityName);
              }
            }
            jsonReader.endObject();
          }
          jsonReader.endObject();
        }
      }
      jsonReader.endObject();
      jsonReader.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }
```

JSON file as requested:

```
{
  "Activities": {
  "Cold Drink": {
    "required": "kitchenDoor",
    "optional": "cup",
    "optional": "fridge",
    "required": "juice"
  },
  "Hot Drink": {
    "required": "kitchenDoor",
    "required": "cup",
    "required": "water",
    "required": "kettle",
    "optional": "sugar",
    "required": "microwave",
    "required": "tea/coffee"
  },
  "Hot Food": {
    "required": "kitchenDoor",
    "optional": "fridge",
    "optional": "plateCupboard",
    "required": "microwave",
    "optional": "cutlery",
    "optional": "chair"
  }
}}
```

Example:

If the value to match was `chair` the program would then print out `Hot Food` and `optional`.

Comment: Please include your json, drink.json in question

Comment: Edited question to include JSON.

Comment: can you show an example of desired output(with example)?

Comment: Agree with @nafas. Share your goal. Also why same key repeating in your JSON? If more then one value in `optional`, then it should be array. And what is `testHarnessSensor`?

Comment: Updated post with example and `testHarnessSensor` definition (it's the value to be matched).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of taking `currentActivity` as `ArrayList`, use `HashMap`. So replace the first line of your code as follow:

```
Map<String, String> currentActivity = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Now replace 3rd inner while loop, where you matching `testHarnessSensor`, with following while loop:

```
                while (jsonReader.hasNext()) {                    
                  String activityAttribute = jsonReader.nextName();
                  String n = jsonReader.nextString();                 
                  if (testHarnessSensor.equals(n)) {                 
                    currentActivity.put(activityName, activityAttribute);
                  }
                }
```

The map `currentActivity` will have the expected results. To print each key-value pair, use following code:

```
                for(String key : currentActivity.keySet()){
                    System.out.println(key + " : " + currentActivity.get(key));
                }
```

Comment: This seems to have worked, it is printing out `Hot Drink=required, Cold Drink=optional` is there any way to access these values separately like you would in an array?

Comment: When I print the whole hash map it prints the values but when I try to use `.get(int)` it returns null.

Comment: To access values from `HashMap`, you need to use keys. I have edited answer.